I am running TTL 232R library and trying to compile examples given in library getting this error
I am trying to compile the main.c file in Linux environment there are three header files included in main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

getting the errors...
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKGcfmV.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `FT_Open'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `FT_ResetDevice'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `FT_SetBaudRate'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `FT_SetDataCharacteristics'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `FT_SetDtr'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x396): undefined reference to `FT_SetFlowControl'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x3c9): undefined reference to `FT_SetRts'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x406): undefined reference to `FT_SetTimeouts'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x451): undefined reference to `FT_Write'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x4dd): undefined reference to `FT_Close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]". Then come back and provide a [mre] and the command line(s) you use to build. It seems as if you forgot to add the library containing the missing functions, but we need to see your code and the commands.

Have you included the library, that contains the FT_* functions?

Thank you for your reply @wiimm, I have included the header files and library but while linking its not getting the particular library not able link it

@user27259546 The error messages typically indicate that a required library has not been included. Usually, the library is included using -l<NAME>.

Please do not let us assume, add the command lines.

I have library with name (libftd2xx.so) but its not taking while compiling the code..
I have installed library and then trying to compile source code and getting this errors..
my source file name is main.c, compiling it with gcc main.c

@Wiimm I have tried with -l<libftd2xx.so> but no resolution getting this error...

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

@user - You are not supposed to type the < and > characters, they are only to show that NAME is not the real name. And they are certainly confusing bash, seing them as I/O redirects.

Still, please [edit] your question to add the command lines, as any other new information.

@BoP I tried the same without <>, it is not working

It would be -lftd2xx, not -l<libftd2xx.so>.

Thank you @AKX I tried its not working getting this..
arun@arun-VirtualBox:~/Documents/release/examples/write$ -lftd2xx
-lftd2xx: command not found

arun@arun-VirtualBox:~/Documents/release/examples/write$ sudo -lftd2xx
sudo: invalid option -- 'f'
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-ABkNnS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-ABkNnS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user]
[-u user] [command [arg ...]]
usage: sudo [-ABbEHkNnPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D directory]
[-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-T timeout]
[-u user] [VAR=value] [-i | -s] [command [arg ...]]

You might want to read the comments, understand them, and follow the advices. This is not a forum, comments are not for new information. And please get used to copy text as text, not as screenshot.

@ArunS - You just cannot guess the command line, so might want to read up on the options available (there are many to choose from) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Your command to built the application lacks the option to link the library.
Try this:
gcc main.c -lftd2xx

Please be aware that the resulting binary has the default name of a.out, which might not be what you want.
I suggest to learn a bit more about general usage of compilers, linkers, and GCC as your actual compiler.
